# How to find repated value in array without using predefined function?

Tags: php

Php How to find repeated value count in array without using predefined function?

$array = array_count_values($array);

Comment: Sort it, then count manually; or create an associative array, in which the original value will be key, and count will be value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
  empty($results[$value]) ? $results[$value] = 1: $results[$value] ++;
}
```